# Download Manager Broadcast Receiver and loop through listview

Tags: android, listview

I have an app with list view of downloadable files. i used Download Manager for handling multiple downloads. Now my problem is i need to update list view row of completed download so in Broadcast Receiver i lop through list view rows to find appropriate row of data and update it but i receive Null pointer Exception in 6th item in list view.

```
BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

        final ListView listView = getListView();
        String[] a = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
            View v = listView.getChildAt(i);
            TextView et = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dmrefrence);
            Log.d( "position",et.getText().toString() );
            Log.d( "i",Integer.toString(i) );
            if(et.getText().toString() == Long.toString(referenceId) ){

                ImageButton cancelButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
                cancelButton.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            }

        }

      }
};//end of broadcast reciever
```

here it is my Adapter:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.pid); // title
    final TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.price); // duration
    final TextView fileurl = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.furl); // fileurl
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); // thumb image

    final TextView refrenceid = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.dmrefrence); // refrence id

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_PID));
    artist.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_NAME));
    duration.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_PRICE));
    fileurl.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_FILEURL));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_DESCRIPTION), thumb_image);

    final ImageButton pauseButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton); // image button

    final ImageButton imageButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); // image button
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to download product
            final String dfileurl = fileurl.getText().toString();
            final String fname = artist.getText().toString();

            imageButton.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            pauseButton.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            HomeFragment x = new HomeFragment();
            //x.new DownloadFileFromURL().doInBackground(dfileurl);
            //DownlmActivity x = new DownlmActivity();
            long id = x.myClickdwnl(fname,dfileurl,pauseButton,activity.getApplicationContext());
            refrenceid.setText(Long.toString(id));

            //Log.d("id",Long.toString(id));
       }
    });
    /* Cancel Download */
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to download product
            final String dnid = refrenceid.getText().toString();
            pauseButton.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            imageButton.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            HomeFragment x = new HomeFragment();

            x.Canceldwnl(dnid,activity.getApplicationContext());

       }
    });

    return vi;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you add a comment to the line throwing the `NullPointerException ` to make it easier to spot the problem?

Comment: this line:  TextView et = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dmrefrence);

Comment: What kind of `Adapter` are you using for your `ListView`? If I was facing this problem, I would use the `Adapter` (`listView.getAdapter()`) to update the underlying data and then call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on my Adapter to refresh the content of the `ListView`.

Comment: when i just loop through visible positions it just works fine, problem is in invisible positions. i am newbie in android programming so i have no idea how can i make my adapter to do changes for me. my adapter is BaseAdapter.

Comment: This is because invisible items (what you call positions) are not children of the `ListView`. In fact invisible items have no `View`. As you scroll, the `ListView` will remove the `View` of the items that become invisible and call your `Adapter`'s `getView()` method to create the `View` for the items that become visible. This is why you should use you `Adapter` to access get the item you want to update. Please post the code of your `Adapter` and I'll show you how.

Comment: i just updated my question, thanks nstCactus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start your download, you get an download id from the following instruction:

```
long id = x.myClickdwnl(fname,dfileurl,pauseButton,activity.getApplicationContext());
```

You need to keep track of which download correspond to a given position (if any) and of the items (rows) which download is finished. In order to do this, add these 2 members to your `BaseAdapter`:

```
/** This associates your download_id to the position of the item in the ListView */
private LongSparseArray<int> downloadIdToPositionMap = new LongSparseArray();

/** This keeps track of the position of item which download is finished */
private ArrayList<Integer> finishedDownloadPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Now in your `imageButton`'s `OnClickListener`, instead of storing the download_id in a `TextView` (which is not what it is intended for anyway), you can store it in the `downloadIdToPositionMap`:

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // starting background task to download product
        final String dfileurl = fileurl.getText().toString();
        final String fname = artist.getText().toString();

        imageButton.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        pauseButton.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        HomeFragment x = new HomeFragment();
        //x.new DownloadFileFromURL().doInBackground(dfileurl);
        //DownlmActivity x = new DownlmActivity();
        long id = x.myClickdwnl(fname,dfileurl,pauseButton,activity.getApplicationContext());
        downloadIdToPositionMap.put(id, position);

        //Log.d("id",Long.toString(id));
   }
});
```

From your `BroadcastReceiver`, you must inform your `Adapter` that a download has finished. You'll need to add another method in your `BaseAdapter` to do this:

```
/**
 * Keep the position of the item associated to the {@code downloadId} in the list of finished downloads
 * @param downloadId the download unique identifier
 * @throws IllegalStateException if there is no entry matching {@code downloadId} in {@code this.downloadIdToPositionMap}
 */
public void setDownloadFinished(long downloadId) throws IllegalStateException{
    int position = this.downloadIdToPositionMap.get(downloadId, -1);
    if(position == -1) throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Unknown finished download with id = %d", downloadId));
    this.finishedDownloadPositions.add(position);
}
```

And change your `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive()` methods to:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

    final BaseAdapter adapter = getListView().getAdapter();
    adapter.setDownloadFinished(referenceId);

    // Ask the adapter to refresh the ListView
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now you know which `ListView` item a finished download corresponds to, given a download_id. The only thing missing is to update the `View` of the row. You'll need to change your `BaseAdapter`'s `getView()` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView == null) vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.pid); // title
    final TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.price); // duration
    final TextView fileurl = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.furl); // fileurl
    ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); // thumb image

    final TextView refrenceid = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.dmrefrence); // refrence id

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_PID));
    artist.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_NAME));
    duration.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_PRICE));
    fileurl.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_FILEURL));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_DESCRIPTION), thumb_image);

    if(this.isDownloadFinished(position)){    
        final ImageButton pauseButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton); // image button
        final ImageButton imageButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); // image button
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // starting background task to download product
                final String dfileurl = fileurl.getText().toString();
                final String fname = artist.getText().toString();

                imageButton.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                pauseButton.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                HomeFragment x = new HomeFragment();
                //x.new DownloadFileFromURL().doInBackground(dfileurl);
                //DownlmActivity x = new DownlmActivity();
                long id = x.myClickdwnl(fname,dfileurl,pauseButton,activity.getApplicationContext());
                refrenceid.setText(Long.toString(id));
                downloadIdToPositionMap.put(id, position);

                //Log.d("id",Long.toString(id));
            }
        });
        /* Cancel Download */
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // starting background task to download product
                final String dnid = refrenceid.getText().toString();
                pauseButton.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                imageButton.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                HomeFragment x = new HomeFragment();

                x.Canceldwnl(dnid,activity.getApplicationContext());

            }
        });
    }
    return vi;
}
```

Finally, add this method (to your `BaseAdapter`) to check if a download is finished, given a position:

```
/**
 * Return wether the given position corresponds to an item which download is finished
 * @param position the position of the item
 * @return  {@code true} if the download associated with the item at position is finished, {@code false} otherwise
 */
private boolean isDownloadFinished(int position){
    return this.finishedDownloadPositions.contains(position);
}
```

---

*Please note that I haven't tested the code so it may contain a few error but you should be able to fix them if you got the logic behind.*

On a side note, you do way too much in your `getItem()` method. Keep in mind that when you scroll your `ListView`, it gets called every time an item gets visible. To avoid lags, you should consider implementing the [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder).

Also avoid using anonymous declarations for your `OnClickListener`s.
In you code, `pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {// Stripped method body for readability});` will crete a new `OnClickListener` for each visible item in your `ListView`. You can avoid it by defining your listener as a new member in your `BaseAdapter` like this:

```
private View.OnClickListener pauseListener = new new View.OnClickListener() {     
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Stripped method body for readability
    }
});

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Stripped method body for readability
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(this.pauseListener);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help and perfect guide,you are the one. tnx tnx tnx ...